# Opening 'comgooglemaps://' uri is opening another app. - iOS

Tags: ios, apache, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

While opening google maps in iOS by using scheme `comgooglemaps://` , It is opening another app named [Pitch Gauge](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pitch-gauge/id389715382). I also confirm that Google Maps app is installed in my iPhone. Still its not picking the url scheme of Google Maps app and trigerring for Pitch Gauge App.

I am using the code given below with cordovaInAppBrowser.

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open( "comgooglemaps://?q=" + address, "_system");
```

Want to know if there any change in URL scheme in iOS for redirecting to Google Maps. Or there's any need to make change related scheme url in iOS?

Comment: It seems likely that that app has also registered the comgooglemaps URL scheme. Unfortunately there is nothing to prevent any app from registering any URL scheme. And iOS does not provide a mechanism for selecting which app should be used to respond to a particular URL.

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: Somehow not looked further on this.